# Can we define x-rays as as decelerated electrons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, radiation, x-rays

HI I'm a student and i was reading up about x-ray production. I realized that after the electrons hit the metal plate( usually tungsten) x-radiation is produced. Is it that the metal ironizes and the the effect is x-radiation?

Comment: No. Accelerated charges produce photons. Search term is bremsstrahlung.

Comment: Are you asking if electrons transform into photons?

Comment: I am asking if x-radiation is caused because of the electrons.

Answer (score 1):

No, X-rays cannot be electrons. An electronic beam is made of charged particles and carries a current. Therefore a magnetic field should be able to bend an X-ray beam. This is something that does not happen in experiments. Therefore an X-ray beam cannot be made of electrons.

Answer (score 0):

for x-rays created by bombarding a metal target with an energetic electron beam, the x-rays are produced when an incoming electron manages to knock an inner electron out of its orbital, after which another electron falls down into that orbital and sheds its excess energy as a photon in the X-ray range.

X-rays are also produced which the collision described above is inelastic, in which case the incoming electron is slowed down and it sheds its kinetic energy as an X-ray photon.

The first mechanism produces X-rays with a certain characteristic energy and the second produces X-rays with a broad spread of energies.

Comment: And bremsstrahlung…